# Will Eigen::Tensor contraction be faster after some transpose? Like place all contracted indices in a specific order in advance?

Tags: c++, eigen, tensor

I have two array of Eigen::Tensor, A, B. The tensors in each array have the same rank. And in my program I will contract one tensor in A array and one tensor in B array according to some rules(this rule will gurantee the dimension match). And the contraction indices are the same. I will do this a lot of times. For example, the tensors in A have rank 3, the tensors in B have rank 4 and I want to contract between indices 0,2 in tensors in array A and 1,2 in tensors in array B.

So I am wondering if it will be better to first permutate them since I know that tensor contraction are mostly implemented as first reshape to a matrix and then do matrix multiplication.

I have tried a minial example as follows but the result is not what I expected since the executing time are similar.

```
#include <unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
typedef std::complex<double> cplx;

int main()
{
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> t0,t1;
    Eigen::Tensor<cplx,3> a(200,100,90);
    a.setRandom();
    Eigen::Tensor<cplx,3> b(200,50,100);
    b.setRandom();
    t0= std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    Eigen::array<Eigen::IndexPair<int>, 1> product_dims = {Eigen::IndexPair<int>(0,0)};
    for(int i=0;i<10;++i)
        Eigen::Tensor<cplx,4> c=a.contract(b,product_dims);
    t1= std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout<<std::setprecision(12)<<" in time: "<<1*1e-10*(double)std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t1-t0).count()<<"s"<<std::endl;

    Eigen::Tensor<cplx,3> dd=a.shuffle(std::vector{1,2,0});
    Eigen::Tensor<cplx,3> ee=b.shuffle(std::vector{1,2,0});

    t0= std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    product_dims = {Eigen::IndexPair<int>(2,2)};
    for(int i=0;i<10;++i)
        Eigen::Tensor<cplx,4> c=dd.contract(ee,product_dims);
    t1= std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout<<std::setprecision(12)<<" in time: "<<1*1e-10*(double)std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t1-t0).count()<<"s"<<std::endl;

    t0= std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    product_dims = {Eigen::IndexPair<int>(2,0)};
    for(int i=0;i<10;++i)
         Eigen::Tensor<cplx,4> c=dd.contract(b,product_dims);
    t1= std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout<<std::setprecision(12)<<" in time: "<<1*1e-10*(double)std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t1-t0).count()<<"s"<<std::endl;

    t0= std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    product_dims = {Eigen::IndexPair<int>(0,2)};
    for(int i=0;i<10;++i)
        Eigen::Tensor<cplx,4> c=a.contract(ee,product_dims);
    t1= std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout<<std::setprecision(12)<<" in time: "<<1*1e-10*(double)std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t1-t0).count()<<"s"<<std::endl;

}
```

I am testing on mac os and compilation command is `-O3 -march=native -std=c++17`. The time is :

```
 in time: 2.4562778s
 in time: 2.4876118s
 in time: 2.4699632s
 in time: 2.4621803s
```